# Add Static route to Ubuntu on a Digital Ocean VPS

Tags: networking, vpn, openswan

I am trying to add a static route to a remote subnet from a digital ocean vps (ubuntu 14.08) but everytime i run the following command I get the error:

```
"RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable"
```

my public ip is X.X.X.X and the remote gateway and host is Y.Y.Y.Y and Z.Z.Z.Z respectively.

```
# ip route add Z.Z.Z.Z via Y.Y.Y.Y
```

I believe my VPS has a default route setup by digitalocean, but i have been able to setup a VPN network with the remote gateway already I just cannot ping the remote host Z.Z.Z.Z or telnet to a port. I confirmed the VPN is up.

Answer (score 0):

I use the route command to add a static route to a specific host or network:

```
# route add -host <destination IP address> gw <gateway IP address>
# route add <destination IP address> gw <gateway IP address>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35483/discussion-on-answer-by-moktod-add-static-route-to-ubuntu-on-a-digital-ocean-vps).

Answer (score 0):

```
root@heisenberg:~# service ipsec status
IPsec running  - pluto pid: 1092
pluto pid 1092
1 tunnels up
```

---

```
root@heisenberg:~# ipsec auto status
ipsec auto: warning: obsolete command syntax used
000 using kernel interface: netkey
000 interface lo/lo ::1
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
000 interface eth0/eth0 104.131.13.155
000 interface eth0/eth0 104.131.13.155
000 %myid = (none)
000 debug none
000
000 virtual_private (%priv):
000 - allowed 6 subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 25.0.0.0/8, fd00::/8, fe80::/10
000 - disallowed 0 subnets:
000 WARNING: Disallowed subnets in virtual_private= is empty. If you have
000          private address space in internal use, it should be excluded!
000
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=2, name=ESP_DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=64, keysizemax=64
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=3, name=ESP_3DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=192, keysizemax=192
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=6, name=ESP_CAST, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=7, name=ESP_BLOWFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=448
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=11, name=ESP_NULL, ivlen=0, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=12, name=ESP_AES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=13, name=ESP_AES_CTR, ivlen=8, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=14, name=ESP_AES_CCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=15, name=ESP_AES_CCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=16, name=ESP_AES_CCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=18, name=ESP_AES_GCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=19, name=ESP_AES_GCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=20, name=ESP_AES_GCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=22, name=ESP_CAMELLIA, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=252, name=ESP_SERPENT, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=253, name=ESP_TWOFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=1, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_MD5, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=2, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA1, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=5, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_256, keysizemin=256, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=6, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_384, keysizemin=384, keysizemax=384
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=7, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_512, keysizemin=512, keysizemax=512
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=8, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_RIPEMD, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=9, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_AES_CBC, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=251, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_NULL_KAME, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=0, name=(null), blocksize=16, keydeflen=131
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=5, name=OAKLEY_3DES_CBC, blocksize=8, keydeflen=192
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=7, name=OAKLEY_AES_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=1, name=OAKLEY_MD5, hashsize=16
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=2, name=OAKLEY_SHA1, hashsize=20
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=4, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_256, hashsize=32
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=6, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_512, hashsize=64
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=2, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=5, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1536, bits=1536
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=14, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=15, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP3072, bits=3072
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=16, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP4096, bits=4096
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=17, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP6144, bits=6144
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=18, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP8192, bits=8192
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=22, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=23, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH23, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=24, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH24, bits=2048
000
000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,5,64} trans={0,5,3072} attrs={0,5,2048}
```

000
   000 "globacom-vpn":  104.131.13.155/32===104.131.13.155<104.131.13.155>:17/1701---104.131.0.1...41.203.65.124<41.203.65.124>===10.100.108.0/24; erouted; eroute owner: #5
   000 "globacom-vpn":     myip=104.131.13.155; hisip=10.100.108.51;
   000 "globacom-vpn":   ike_life: 86400s; ipsec_life: 3600s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 3
   000 "globacom-vpn":   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 32,24; interface: eth0;
   000 "globacom-vpn":   dpd: action:clear; delay:10; timeout:20;
   000 "globacom-vpn":   newest ISAKMP SA: #4; newest IPsec SA: #5;
   000 "globacom-vpn":   IKE algorithms wanted: AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1536(5), AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1024(2), AES_CBC(7)_128-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1536(5), AES_CBC(7)_128-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1024(2), 3DES_CBC(5)_000-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1536(5), 3DES_CBC(5)_000-SHA1(2)_000-MODP1024(2); flags=-strict
   000 "globacom-vpn":   IKE algorithms found:  AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1536(5)AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1024(2)AES_CBC(7)_128-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1536(5)AES_CBC(7)_128-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1024(2)3DES_CBC(5)_192-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1536(5)3DES_CBC(5)_192-SHA1(2)_160-MODP1024(2)
   000 "globacom-vpn":   IKE algorithm newest: 3DES_CBC_192-SHA1-MODP1024
   000 "globacom-vpn":   ESP algorithms wanted: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_000, AES(12)_128-SHA1(2)_000, 3DES(3)_000-SHA1(2)_000; flags=-strict
   000 "globacom-vpn":   ESP algorithms loaded: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160, AES(12)_128-SHA1(2)_160, 3DES(3)_192-SHA1(2)_160
   000 "globacom-vpn":   ESP algorithm newest: 3DES_000-HMAC_SHA1; pfsgroup=
   000
   000 #5: "globacom-vpn":500 STATE_QUICK_I2 (sent QI2, IPsec SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 2048s; newest IPSEC; eroute owner; isakmp#4; idle; import:admin initiate
   000 #5: "globacom-vpn" esp.5afe00ef@41.203.65.124 esp.c719225f@104.131.13.155 tun.0@41.203.65.124 tun.0@104.131.13.155 ref=0 refhim=4294901761
   000 #4: "globacom-vpn":500 STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established);        EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 85210s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=10s(seq in:1782 out:0); idle;     import:admin initiate
   000

Comment: That's how i know it is up. It has also been confirmed up by the admin at the remote host.